# How to iterate all child properties recursively while setting values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a tree view class.

```
public class TreeNode
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public HashSet<TreeNode> ChildNodes {get;set;}
     public TreeNode ParentNode {get;set;}
     public bool IsExpanded {get;set;}
}
```

All tree items have IsExpanded = false by default.

When I get the leaf node, I need to expand the node and all its parent nodes, all the way up to the root node.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
//
// This method will return all Ids for the node and all its parent nodes.
//
private IEnumerable<int> YieldIdsRecursively(TreeNode node)
{
     yield return node.Id;
     if (node.ParentNode is not null)
     {
          foreach (int id in YieldIdsRecursively(node.ParentNode))
          {
               yield return id;
          }
     }
}

//
// I wanted to use the ref modifier to set the Id property of each node.
// However, properties are not supported by the ref modifier in c#
//
private void ExpandNodesRecursively(IEnumerable<int> ids, ref HashSet<TreeNode> nodes)
{
     foreach(var node in nodes)
     {
          if(ids.Contains(node))
          {
               node.IsExpanded = true;
          }

          if((node.ChildNodes?.Count ?? 0) > 0)
          {
               //
               // This is where the error pops
               //
               ExpandNodesRecursively(ids, node.ChildNodes);
          }
     }
}
```

Any advises would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First: no  `ref` needed Second: Use `if(ids.Contains(node.Id))` instead of `if(ids.Contains(node))`

Comment: You really don't want to use an iterator (`yield`) for this purpose. Also, as noted in another comment, `ref` shouldn't be required.

Comment: Why just not make simply version - while iterate from leaf to root set `IsExpanded = true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think it's easier to return `TreeNode` itself instead of its `Id`:

```
private IEnumerable<TreeNode> ThisAndAllParents() {
  for (TreeNode current = this; current != null; current = current.ParentNode)
    yield return current;
}
```

then `ExpandNodesRecursively` can be something like this:

```
private void ExpandNodesRecursively() {
  foreach (TreeNode node in ThisAndAllParents())
    node.IsExpanded = true; 
}
```